# Get facebook albums and album images?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Hello Friends**

I am trying to get facebook album of a user . Problem is that it is returning albums for the user who is created the facebook app or who is the admin of that application .

For rest of the users it is returning the empty array

```
new Request(session, "/me/albums", null, HttpMethod.GET,
                        new Request.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                System.out.println("Responce "
                                        + response.getGraphObject());
                            }
                        }).executeAsync();
```

This work for me because i have create a facebook app  and for the rest of the users it is not returning the data. Please let me know how to resolve this.

**Thanks
Amit**

Comment: Please sugest me some solutions

Comment: Plz see my ans...it's ios ans but may be helped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Answer (score 0):

When your application is in sandbox/development mode you can not perform any api call for other user. To test your for other user, add the user as a tester, developer or admin. See details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/)

Comment: how to change the mode please sugest

Comment: You have to publish your facebook app and make public to other user. just go to setting>Status & Review .

Comment: One more thing your will be publicly accessible after the reviewing process.

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably ask for the user_photos permission already (else it would not work for the admin), there are two possible problems why it does not work for other users:

- Your App is in not set public. Go to the "Status & Review" tab of your App settings and make sure that checkbox on top says "YES".
- Most permissions (like user_photos) need to get reviewed by Facebook before you can use them for any other user: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login